# use not equal to in custom function in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have made a function named `__getwheredata` in `MY_Controller`:

```
public function __getwheredata($tablename,$tablefield=array(),$where=array(),$orderbyfield = 'id',$ascdesc = 'desc',$limit = 200,$offset='')
{
    if(is_array($tablefield)){$tablefield = implode(',',$tablefield);}
    print_r($where);exit;
    $data = $this->db
                ->select($tablefield)
                ->from($tablename)
                ->where($where)
                ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
                ->limit($limit,$offset)
                ->get();
    return $data->result();
}
```

I need to get data where **`field is not equal to 1`**.

so I call the function like:

```
$this->Usermodel->__getwheredata('users','*',array('rights!='=>1),'id','desc',NULL);
```

but here `array('rights!='=>1)` will pass as array in value of the `where` condition.

so how can I resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to stringify the whole array like this:

```
$temp = '';
$index = 1;
$count = count($where);
foreach($where as $key => $value)
{
    $temp .= $key.$value;
    if($index < $count) $temp .= ',';
    $index++;
}
$where = $temp;
```

Now it will generate where statements as a string like this `rights!=1`

---

**Edit:** or you can do it like this:

```
foreach($where as $key => $value)
{
    $this->db->where($key, $value);
}
```

---

Now your function would look like this:

```
foreach($where as $key => $value)
{
    $this->db->where($key, $value);
}
$data = $this->db->select($tablefield)
             ->from($tablename)
             ->order_by($orderbyfield, $ascdesc)
             ->limit($limit,$offset)
             ->get();
```

Comment: i dont want string as not equals to requires like `where('field !=' , 1);`

Comment: You can pass a string and escape values by adding a third parameter to `where($string, NULL, FALSE);` but if you need to follow the rules i'll update my answer to match it.